# What does shapely module return for intersection of objects as third dimension coordinate?

Tags: python, spatial, shapely, geos

I have two trajectories saved as Linestring objects in shapely, each Linestring containing a list of tuples, each tuple would be a point(Easting_Utm, Northing_utm, Time_in_unix)
I know that both trajectories intersect.

I need to find the moment that each of the objects would arrive to the intersection point. I'm using shapely module to make 2D spatial computation, and as third paramether im inserting time unit.

For example, `Point=(x,y,z)`, being z the moment that object was at position x,y. When computing intersection between two Linestrings, that have a list of tuples (x,y,z), I should get a point (x_intersection,y_intersection), and a z coordinate, being the moment Linestring1 or Linestring2 arrive to that point. Would that even be possible? 
Remember that shapely only does 2D spatial calculations, but allows a third parameter (z) when creating objects, which in my case is the time in unix.

I have already tried, and I get, this result, but the third parameter has no intuition for me of what has shapely done:

```
Linestring1=(List of tuples)--> First trajectory
Linestring2=(List of tuples)--> Second trajectory
```

I compute:
`Linestring1.intersection(Linestring2)`, and I get this result.

`[(604773.0962574851, 5792804.393592814, 1557932495.6671839)]`

(Being the first element of the tuple Easting_UTM, the second Northing_UTM, and the third time in unix...) I basically want to know what does shapely do with that third coordinate internaly.

Thanks beforehand!!

I should get the intersection point between the two trajectories (linestrings), and as a third parameter the time any of the two trajectories would arrive to that point

Answer (score 1):

To calculate this Z value, `geos` (the underlying library of `shapely`) starts by computing the 2D location of the intersection, then it does a linear interpolation of the Z value on each of the linestrings, then it takes the average of the two Z values.

Consider the following snippet

```
l1 = LineString([(0, 0, 4), (1, 1, 5)])
l2 = LineString([(0, 1, 12), (1, 0, 13)])
```

which represent two linestrings crossing on their center, we can determine that the computed Z value might be `((4+5) / 2) + (12+13) / 2) / 2 = 8.5`

```
result = l1.intersection(l2)
print(result.coords[0]) # (0.5, 0.5, 8.5)
```